# An animation queue bug of carousel

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple carousel case ,but it has an animation problem.

When you click prev or next button quickly,list items show fast too.

How to fix it?

**code is here:**

#### html:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="play">
        <!-- initialize play number -->
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var containner=$('#carousel');
        var pagination=containner.find('.pagination');
        var play=containner.find('.play');
        var picList=containner.find('.pic ul li');
        var prev=pagination.find('.prev');
        var next=pagination.find('.next');
        var pageNum=0;
        var defaultAnimateDelay={
            show:800,
            hide:100
        };
        // initialize play number
        (function(picListLength){
            var playHtml='';
            for(var i=0; i<picListLength; i++){
                playHtml+='<a href="#" data-number="'+i+'">'+(i+1)+'</a>';
            }
            play.html(playHtml);
        })(picList.length);
        // 
        function Carousel(pageNumber){
            picList.eq(pageNumber)
            .stop(false,false)
            .animate({
                opacity:'show'
            },defaultAnimateDelay.show).siblings()
            .stop(false,false).animate({
                opacity:'hide'
            },defaultAnimateDelay.hide);
            // add Current class to current play number
            play.find('a')
            .eq(pageNumber)
            .addClass('current')
            .siblings('').removeClass('current');
        }
        // click prev event
        prev.on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(pageNum===0){
                pageNum=(picList.length-1);
            }else {
                pageNum--;
            }
            Carousel(pageNum);
        });
        // click next event
        next.on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(pageNum===(picList.length-1)){
                pageNum=0;
            }else{
                pageNum++;
            }
            Carousel(pageNum);
        });
        //  play number 
        play.on('click','a',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            pageNum=Number($(this).attr('data-number'));
            Carousel(pageNum);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Bootstrap carousel js works well,but it does not use jquery stop function.Amazing.

Comment: I can't see anything that needs to be fixed. You'll need to show us your code.

Comment: please post the code, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: ^^ guys, open your eyes. click the link and u will see the code. No reason for downvote!

Comment: @RobertP. That's not how SO works. That would mean we are here to personally fix OPs problem without it being useful to others.

Comment: couple things: 1) post your code, you cannot expect that JS fiddle wont go down and if it were there would be no context to your question. 2) you need to do a little more explaining of what you expected vs what you are seeing and what you have tried to resolve it. 3) Hopefully my answer does what you are asking

Comment: I have made a demo on my jsFiddle.

Comment: Answer updated to fix bug on initial load.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP refuses to post his / her code meaning there will be a crap question left once the link goes dead.

Comment: I'm sorry,it's my first practice.Now, i have posted my code,please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code everything happens immediately. There are no callbacks and thus no waiting for the animations to end. Your code can be reorganized to make it a bit more readable and easier to refactor. Here is what i would try:

```
function show(pageNumber){
    return picList.eq(pageNumber)
    .animate({
        opacity:'show'
    },defaultAnimateDelay.show).promise();
}

function hide(pageNumber){
    return picList.eq(pageNumber)
    .stop(false,true)
    .siblings()
    .stop(false,false)
    .animate({
        opacity:'hide'
    },defaultAnimateDelay.hide).promise();
}

function Carousel(pageNumber){
    var promise = hide(pageNumber);
    promise.done(function(){
        show(pageNumber);
    });

    play.find('a')
    .eq(pageNumber)
    .addClass('current')
    .siblings('').removeClass('current');
}
```

This ensures that the hide animation completes before beginning the show animation. Another option would be to use the built-in callbacks but i find this easier to follow. I am not sure if all the `stop` statements are necessary but left them in.

Another issue (one that effects the initial page state) is that nothing is initially hidden. To resolve that is just simply updating the init code as follows:

```
(function(picListLength){
    var playHtml='';
    for(var i=0; i<picListLength; i++){
        playHtml+='<a href="#" data-number="'+i+'">'+(i+1)+'</a>';
    }
    play.html(playHtml);
    hide(0); // hide all but one
})(picList.length);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/CUYbL/

JQuery Promise: http://api.jquery.com/promise/